# Adding a link within .textContent in javascript?

Tags: javascript, text, hyperlink

```js
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">日本語</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementsByClassName("childdiv")[0].childNodes[1].textContent="私について.link("Aboutme.html") | ギャラリー.link("Gallery.html") | 連絡.link("contact.html")";
}
</script>
<div class="childdiv">
<h3 id="english">&nbsp;<a href="Aboutme.html">About me</a> | <a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a> | <a href="contact.html">Contact</a></h3>
```

This is the code i currently use. Normal text works perfectly, but when using hyperlinks within .textContent the button doesn't even work. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Did you try escaping your quotation marks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: new code below to update text and buttons to Japanese onclick.

```js
//we are targeting the current links by id
var a = document.getElementById('link1');
var b = document.getElementById('link2');
var c = document.getElementById('link3');

//this is for example text 
var p = document.getElementById('example');

//this function will take English links/text and update to Japanese when button is clicked
function myFunction() {
p.innerHTML = "Links and text are now Japanese"
if (a) {
  a.innerHTML = "私について";
  a.href = "私について.link";
}
if (b) {
  b.innerHTML = "私について";
  b.href = "私について.link";
}
if (c) {
  c.innerHTML = "連絡";
  c.href = "連絡.link";
}
}
```

```html
<button id="japanese" type="button" onclick="myFunction();">日本語</button>

<div id="childdiv">
<h3 id="english">&nbsp;<a id="link1" href="Aboutme.html">About me</a> | <a id="link2" href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a> | <a id="link3" href="contact.html">Contact</a></h3>
</div>

<p id="example">Click Button to update links and text to Japanese</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, though it still seems not to be working. The button still does nothing.

Comment: When you click the button, hover over the hyperlinks (about me, gallery, contact). You will see they have updated after click.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, I don't see any difference. What exactly do you mean?https://quicksoapy.xyz/ here is the website with the included code, if that may be of any use.. The main page (index.html) is the one with the button.

Comment: I updated the snippet above with more comments. - You want the English links to change to Japanese when the button is clicked, right? The code above does this.

Comment: Ah thank you so much for the help! Though i actually was trying to update the texts (About me> 私について, Gallery > ギャラリー, Contact > 連絡). Though i was going to try and figure that out later too anyways, so it's not in vain heh.

Comment: AH, see my updated code. It should work as you expect now. - If I have helped your problem, kindly mark the answer as correct by clicking the checkmark as it will help me and others who have a similar issue in the future.